# Extra form data when form is submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some checkboxs(It is already checked by Jquery. But I do uncheck them.) is posted to sever in form submission. But I havn't check it. Please see below.

Here is javascirpt.

```
$('.checkbox').change(function(){
     alert('hi');
});

$('.checkbox[data-img=a]').click();
$('.checkbox[data-img=b]').click();
```

Here is HTML.

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='a' value='a' name='name' />a
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='b' value='b' name='name' />b
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='c' value='c' name='name' />c
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='d' value='d' name='name' />d
```

I call cick event from jquery. So, a and b is alerady checked. Before form submission, I do uncheck a and b and check c and d. But when form is submitting,  I have got a, b, c and d. Actually, I should get only c and d.

I use ASP. When I catch them on server, the following result is appeared.

```
name = Request.Form("name") ' name = "a, b, c, d"
```

When I remove this "$('.checkbox[data-img=a]').click();", it is working well.

```
name = Request.Form("name") ' name = "c, d"
```

I don't know why is it? Somebody please explain about this. Thanks.

Comment: `name='name'` all your checkboxes contains the same name

Comment: how is the form submitted

Comment: Please see my question again. I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `name` attribute should be like `name[]`. This is how it should be

```
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='a' value='a' name='name[]' />a
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='b' value='b' name='name[]' />b
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='c' value='c' name='name[]' />c
<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' data-img='d' value='d' name='name[]' />d
```

When you submit the form, you will get the checkbox results as `name` array and you can process it in the backend.

**EDIT:**

Dont use `click()` function,use the below lines to make **"a" & "b"** values already checked

```
$('.checkbox[data-img=a]').prop('checked',true);
$('.checkbox[data-img=b]').prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: I have done it. But it is not working. But I have to use click function. because I have other purpose for this.

Comment: what other function you have...if you have other function of it, do tell coz there are ways to achieve it

Comment: There is no other function.

Comment: no..I mean what other purpose you have of that click function, coz it can be achieved through other ways

Comment: Now, it is working. I use .trigger('click') instead of .click(). I don't know why?